# I am not getting a popup MODAL in ajax using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ajaxmodal.aspx.cs" Inherits="dummy.testtt.ajaxmodal" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .modalBackground
        {
            background-color: Gray;
            filter: alpha(opacity=50);
            opacity: 0.7;
        }
    </style>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
  <asp:Button ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
            onclick="LinkButton1_Click" />

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" BackColor="White" Height="300px"
        Width="800px" HorizontalAlign="Center">
              <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Ok" runat="server" Text="submit" />
        <asp:Button ID="can" runat="server" Text="cancel" />
    </asp:Panel>


          <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPE" runat="server" TargetControlID="LinkButton1" PopupControlID="Panel1"
        BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="can"></ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this the actual code? You are declaring `TagPrefix="asp"`, while using `<ajaxToolkit:`

Comment: IVE REMOVED THIS LINE .. STILL IM NOT ABLE TO OPEN A POPUP MODAL    <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>